# Multiply by count result

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table called TableA with two columns, Amount and A_ID (A unique ID) and a table called TableB with one column B_ID (Another unique ID)

Doing a select on TableA would present data like this:

```
Amount | A_ID
1378   | 1
1839   | 2
1237   | 1
```

And Table B simply:

```
B_ID
 1
 2
```

I want to be able to count the amount of entries of A_ID where it also exists within B_ID, then multiply TableA Amount by the result of the count function. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT (
SELECT Count(*)
FROM TableA a, TableB b
where a.A_ID = b.B_ID
) id_count, SUM(id_count * a.amount)
from TableA a
GROUP BY a.A_ID
```

With the expected result of:

```
total_Amount | A_ID
   2615      |  1
   1839      |  2
```

Comment: Show the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry about that, I added my expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to count the amount of entries of A_ID where it also exists within B_ID, then multiply TableA Amount by the result of the count function.

I think you simply want:

```
select sum(a.amount)
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.a_id = b.b_id;
```

If you want this per `a_id`:

```
select a.a_id, sum(a.amount)
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.a_id = b.b_id
group by a.a_id;
```

Comment: The second answer was what I was looking for, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use below query:

```sql
selct amount, amount/count from
        (select Amount, count(1) as count from TableA A
        inner join TableB B
        on (A.A_ID = B.B_ID)
        group by Amount);
```